# How can I plot like this in spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I'd like to plot my outcome like this with secondary axis.

[image]

My outcome now is:

[image]

Comment: Spyder is just an ide. You will need to change someting in the package you are using, which im guessing is matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Do you want gridlines? If so, you'd just have another line of code similar to this

```
plt.grid(b=True)
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html

Comment: Thank you! It helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that

```
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

is what I want.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found what you were looking for (I didn't even know matplotlib had a fivethiryeight style so I learned something too). In the future, clearly and concisely pointing out the details you're looking for helps both you and us.